# Add character "-" after text in phpword

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

i'm using phpword for creating file word from php.
and i want to make file word by using class php word with text like this

```
example text line 1
example text line 2
line 3
```

and i want the result like this

```
example text line 1 --------------------------------------
example text line 2 --------------------------------------
line 3 ---------------------------------------------------
```

i dont know what is name of this line but i hope some body help me.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$lenght = 50;
$lines = ["example text line 1","example text line 2","line 3"];
foreach($lines as $line)
{
  echo str_pad($line,($lenght-strlen($line)),"-");
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: my question is using PHPWORD... to create word file using php